# Conditional statement value held in variable

Tags: javascript

I'm checking if a function existed with the following if statement:

```
if( typeof functioName !== 'undefined' && $.isFunction(functionName) ) {
 //exists
}
```

However, I would like to hold the if statement in a variable and then check the variable value in the if statement like this:

```
var functionIsReal = typeof functionName !== 'undefined' && $.isFunction(functionName)

if( functionIsReal ) {
  //exists
}
```

I'm getting the correct values if the function exists or if it doesn't, but i would like to know if this is valid, Can I store conditional statements in a variable?

Comment: Yes, it's a value just like anything else.

Comment: You're not storing a statement in the variable, you're just storing the value of the expression.

Comment: Are you hoping that the value of `functionIsReal` will change if you reassign `functionName`?

Comment: You have a typo here: `typeof functioName` is missing the 2nd `n` in `function`.

Comment: Double check your spelling on your first if statement, looks like you want to name it functionName and right now it's functioName

Answer (score 1):

```
var functionIsReal = typeof functionName !== 'undefined' && $.isFunction(functionName);
```

The statement is valid. functionIsReal here actually stores the result of the condition check after evaluating the expression and will be a boolean value.